# R transform character vectors in a list, conditional on the content of the vector

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, character, transform

The problem is I have a list of character vectors.

example:

```
mylist <- list( c("once","upon","a","time"),
                c("once", "in", "olden", "times"),
                c("Let","all","good","men"),
                c("Let","This"),
                c("once", "is","never","enough"),
                c("in","the"),
                c("Come","dance","all","around"))
```

and I want to prepend c("one", "two") to those vectors starting "once" to end up with the list

```
mylist <- list( c("one", "two", "once","upon","a","time"),
                c("one", "two", "once", "in", "olden", "times"),
                c("Let","all","good","men"),
                c("Let","This"),
                c("one", "two", "once", "is","never","enough"),
                c("in","the"),
                c("Come","dance","all","around"))
```

so far

I can select the relevant vectors

```
mylist[grep("once",mylist)]
```

and I can prepend "one" and "two" to create a results list

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist[grep("once",mylist)],FUN = function(listrow) prepend(listrow,c("One","Two")))
```

But putting the results in the correct place in mylist?

Nope, that escapes me!

Hints, tips and solutions most welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `grep` at all. Loop over the list, checking the first value for `"once"` and appending via `c()` the extra values:

```
lapply(mylist, \(x) if(x[1] == "once") c("one", "two", x) else x)
##[[1]]
##[1] "one"  "two"  "once" "upon" "a"    "time"
##
##[[2]]
##[1] "one"   "two"   "once"  "in"    "olden" "times"
##
##[[3]]
##[1] "Let"  "all"  "good" "men" 
##
##[[4]]
##[1] "Let"  "This"
##
##[[5]]
##[1] "one"    "two"    "once"   "is"     "never"  "enough"
##
##[[6]]
##[1] "in"  "the"
##
##[[7]]
##[1] "Come"   "dance"  "all"    "around"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Just for my edification what does  \\(x) mean?

Comment: `\(x)` is a short-hand for `function(x)`, where `x` is a placeholder for each element of `mylist` as it is being looped over by `lapply`.

Answer (score 2):

- We can use

```
lapply(mylist , \(x) if(grepl("once" , x[1])) 
      append(x,  c("one", "two") , 0) else x)
```

- Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "one"  "two"  "once" "upon" "a"    "time"

[[2]]
[1] "one"   "two"   "once"  "in"    "olden" "times"

[[3]]
[1] "Let"  "all"  "good" "men" 

[[4]]
[1] "Let"  "This"

[[5]]
[1] "one"    "two"    "once"   "is"     "never"  "enough"

[[6]]
[1] "in"  "the"

[[7]]
[1] "Come"   "dance"  "all"    "around"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `map_if`

```
library(purrr)
map_if(mylist, .p = ~ first(.x) == "once", .f = ~ c("one", "two", .x))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "one"  "two"  "once" "upon" "a"    "time"

[[2]]
[1] "one"   "two"   "once"  "in"    "olden" "times"

[[3]]
[1] "Let"  "all"  "good" "men" 

[[4]]
[1] "Let"  "This"

[[5]]
[1] "one"    "two"    "once"   "is"     "never"  "enough"

[[6]]
[1] "in"  "the"

[[7]]
[1] "Come"   "dance"  "all"    "around"
```